# Translating from recursive into explicit sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

How can one convert a recursive sequence into an explicit one given the following?
$$a_1=0 $$ $$~a_{n+1} = 0.5a_n + 1$$

Looking at the values of the sequence and their differences $$ 0,1,1.5,1.75,1.875 ... $$
$$1,0.5,0.25,0.125...$$

I still wasn't able to come up with a function describing this relationship. What is the approach one does in such cases?

Any help is very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Noting that $a_n=.5a_{n-1}+1$ and subtracting gives $a_{n+1}-\frac 32 \times a_n+\frac 12\times a_{n-1}$ which is a more standard form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

we have
$$(\forall n,k \ge 2)\;2^ka_n=2^{k-1}a_{n-1}+2^k$$
So

$$2a_2=a_1+2$$
$$2^2a_3=2a_2+2^2$$
$$2^3a_4=2^2a_3+2^3$$

$$\cdots$$
$$2^{n-1}a_n=2^{n-2}a_{n-1}+2^{n-1}$$

the sum gives
$$2^{n-1}a_n=a_1+2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^{n-1}$$

Comment: @dxiv Thanks a lot. I made the correction you said. thanx again.